# Safety of third parties identified in questions

Tags: discussion

The question [Friends girlfriend's parents preventing her from returning to UK from the UAE (Abu-Dhabi)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177790/friends-girlfriends-parents-preventing-her-from-returning-to-uk-from-the-uae-a) is asking for advice on extracting an individual (not the asker) from a situation in which they may be being detained against their will.

The situation is described in enough detail that the individual could reasonably be de-anonymized. This public discussion therefore has the potential to alert parties involved in the detainment, putting the individual at risk and interfering with any other efforts to aid the individual.

Are there any site policies or procedures for handling such concerns?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your question.

> Are there any site policies or procedures for handling such concerns?

The [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) has the following section:

> Users may not post other people's personally identifying or
> confidential information, including but not limited to credit card
> numbers, Social Security Numbers, and driver's and other license
> numbers. You may not post information such as other people's
> passwords, usernames, phone numbers, addresses and e-mail addresses
> unless already publicly accessible on the Web.

The post in question does not contain any significant details that would allow someone to deduce the real name of the person in question. There's a *theoretical* chance of the people in question finding this post on the Internet but keep in mind that:

1. Even our most popular posts rarely get more than 20k views, which is ~0.0001% of global page views on any given day. In other words this website isn't particularly popular on the global scale.
2. Only a minority of the world's population speaks English. The most optimistic estimates say that 1.5 out of the 8 billion people in the world speak it, so only ~20% of the world's population could reasonably read the post without Google Translate.
3. A lot of questions on StackExchange are the result of a misunderstanding or are just made up as a hypothetical situation. The "juicier" the question, the more likely it is to be fiction.

So overall I don't think we should have any concern. If OP makes a request to the mods we can certainly remove/redact the question but until then I'd say we should leave it as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I, however, disagree with your threat assessment. The question provides enough information (e.g., nationality, former nationality, rough age range, sex, country of university study, recent countries visited, time window of arrival) for an investigator with access to border control and/or state surveillance records to narrow down the person in question to no more than a handful of possibilities. ...

Comment: The threat model is not "someone reads this casually and happens to recognize the case". It is more "someone scanning the web for mentions of the country in question picks up the post in their scan, and passes it as a lead to someone else in the security apparatus".

Comment: @RLH the answers to the post suggest that OPs friend contacts the local security apparatus on their own :-) In any case I don't think we should worry about this scenario.

Comment: Those answers are somewhere between "naive" and "dangerous", and appear to be predicated on the answerers' assumption of a modern western socio-legal-security environment.